# Non exhaustive patterns in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell so please understand that my question is kinda dumb. Actually it feels like it.

So I've tried to solve the problem now for a couple of hours..
I've got this

```
data Slot = Slot {
            getTime :: Time,
            getSubject :: Name
            }
deriving(Show,Eq)

 slotListToSlot :: [Slot] -> Slot
 slotListToSlot [] = ???
 slotListToSlot (x:xs) = x
```

The compiler is complaining that there is no pattern for the empty List of Slots.
Of course the questionmarks are just to show where code is missing.

At this point I don't really know what to do.
Any ideas and help is welcome ^^

Comment: Well what is `slotListToSlot` supposed to do?

Comment: Wait, so is this the actual code in your file, with `???` literally appearing?

Comment: @luqui: based on the text, I would say there is no such line in the file. The OP only mentions that to denote the actual problem.

Comment: You can use `undefined` as a temporary placeholder for a pattern that you mean to fill in later, such as, `slotListToSlot [] = undefined`. Be careful: the compiler won’t alert you that you left a pattern undefined!

Comment: All the answers presumes that the OP want the first item in the list. Can the OP confirm that is the intended behavior of the `slotListToSlot` function?

Answer (score 5):

You have three options:

1. Use `Maybe`:

   ```
   slotListToSlot :: [Slot] -> Maybe Slot
   slotListToSlot [] = Nothing
   slotListToSlot (x:xs) = Just x
   ```

   Alternative implementation: use [`listToMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe) in the standard Data.Maybe package:

   ```
   slotListToSlot :: [Slot] -> Maybe Slot
   slotListToSlot = listToMaybe
   ```
2. Use [`Data.List.NonEmpty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmpty):

   ```
   import Data.List.NonEmpty

   slotListToSlot :: NonEmpty Slot -> Slot
   slotListToSlot = neHead
   ```
3. Use `error`:

   ```
   slotListToSlot :: [Slot] -> Slot
   slotListToSlot [] = error "slotListToSlot: empty list"
   slotListToSlot (x:xs) = x
   ```

I would recommend to use the first option, since 2. is unpractical, unless you work with `NonEmpty` everywhere in you program, and 3. is bad practice (makes your program vulnerable, because your function is partial, whereas using Maybe guarantees a crash-free function).

Comment: Every case is explained! Just pick one, very very good, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: There is another option: don't write `slotListToSlot` at all, and simply use `case` in the places where you planned on calling it before. (You're *probably* going to find yourself doing that anyway with the suggested first option.)

Comment: @DanielWagner it depends on how often `slotListToSlot` is currently used in the code. However, with a definition like `slotListToSlot = listToMaybe`, you could just use `listToMaybe` directly, indeed.

Comment: Wow thanks !
Now I understand how to use "Maybe" :)

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want anything in your code but error for empty list, you could do

```
 slotListToSlot :: [Slot] -> Slot
 slotListToSlot [] = error "no slot for empty list"
 slotListToSlot (x:xs) = x
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept any anwer!

Answer (score 4):

Based on your question, it looks like you want to return the *first* element of the list.

There is actually no need to implement such function on your own, since there is already a generic function: [`head :: [a] -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head).

> **Extract the first element** of a list, which must be **non-empty**.

Now of course you cannot return the *head* of an empty list. In that case the function will error:

```
Prelude> head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
Prelude Data.Maybe> head [1]
1
Prelude Data.Maybe> head [1,4]
1
```

Usually in case there are "exceptional circumstances", it is better to use `Maybe`. For instance you can use: [`listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe).

> The `listToMaybe` function returns **`Nothing` on an empty list** or `Just a` where `a` is the **first element** of the list.

This function will thus return the head of the list (wrapped in a `Just`) in case the list contains at least one element, and otherwise `Nothing`. For instance:

```
Prelude> :m Data.Maybe
Prelude Data.Maybe> listToMaybe []
Nothing
Prelude Data.Maybe> listToMaybe [1]
Just 1
Prelude Data.Maybe> listToMaybe [1,4]
Just 1
```

Now the type (`Maybe a`) contains information that there are two scenarios, and calling functions can then handle those (separately).

Comment: Here is an example of a perfect answer, is very nice to read experts :)